# Text-align: center failure. Perhaps positioned wrong?

Tags: html, css

I'm brand new to programming. My apologies for failure to follow any protocol here.

I'm having trouble with my footer text not centering on the page. I have a text-align: center tag but it's failing to register.

Any advice is appreciated.

:)

```
<style>

h2 {
font-family: 'times new roman';
font-style: bold;
font-size: 50px; 
text-align:center;
margin-top: 70px;
margin-left: 120px;
margin-right: 120px;
}

a {
text-align:center;
font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
letter-spacing: 0px; 
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 500;
}

a:link {text-decoration: none;color: black; }
a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: black; }
a:hover { letter-spacing: 20px; background-color: yellow; color: black; }
a:active { background-color: yellow; color: black; }

li {display: inline-block; padding-right: 40px; }       

</style>
</head>


<div style:"position: center">

<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ipsum tortor, pharetra et eleifend in, tristique vel quam. Duis eu leo pretium, tempus sapien in, malesuada est. Integer at lorem nec mi finibus maximus eu sit amet nisi.     </h2>

</div>

<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align:center">
<ul> 
<li><a href="mailto:youremailaddress" target="_blank">E M A I L</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank">T W I T T E R</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">F A C E B O O K</a>    </li>
<li><a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">I N S T A G R A M</a>                </li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of issues:

1. This is not programming, but this is markup.
2. Attributes have `=` not `:`. (`style:"position: center"`)
3. There's no `position: center;`, it should be `text-align: center`.

**Snippet**

```css
h2 {
  font-family: 'times new roman';
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-right: 120px;
}
a {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
a:hover {
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
a:active {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ipsum tortor, pharetra et eleifend in, tristique vel quam. Duis eu leo pretium, tempus sapien in, malesuada est. Integer at lorem nec mi finibus maximus eu sit amet nisi.</h2>
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0; text-align: center; left: 0;">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="mailto:youremailaddress" target="_blank">E M A I L</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank">T W I T T E R</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">F A C E B O O K</a> </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">I N S T A G R A M</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Not sure if this is what you are expecting:

[image: preview]

Comment: Thanks @PraveenKuman! I won't make the markup vs programming mistake again. It is what I am looking for except I'm trying to center the Email... block on the page.

Comment: @bowwowdom I'll help you update the code. Now for the solution, please wait a moment.

Comment: @bowwowdom For the footer div, give this style: `position: absolute;bottom: 0px;right: 0;text-align:center;left: 0;`

Comment: ! I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `width: 100%;` to your footer div's style.
Also, there are a couple other problems with your code...

There is no position: center. See these for valid values: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position and 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

HTML attributes use "=" to set and not ":".

Comment: Why do you need `margin: auto`, when you are giving `width: 100%`? Can you quote a different website other than W3Schools? How is this answer better than mine?

Comment: That's true he doesn't need the margin setting too. Edited. Sure I added another source besides W3Schools.  I offered a solution to his footer problem. You centered his main content text.

Comment: Thanks @petryuno1! It works---except it adds a horizontal scrollbar. Is there a way to remove this?